# Twilio Voice SDK - Capture Client Identity for Incoming and outgoing calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-sdk

I have implemented Twilio Voice JS SDK to make/receive outgoing/incoming calls from within browser.

Using the status callbacks, I get to know when the call was initiated, ringing, in progress and completed.

However, I am not able to find and record which user made/answered a call (All users have different log id and different client identity id).

When the Incoming call is received, incoming event is triggered on voice client (browser), however, there is no call information availale (call SID etc) to record it.

Similarly, when an outgoing call is made, Call SID information is not available.

Code for incoming calls and to record callsid

```
device.on("incoming", handleIncomingCall);

  function handleIncomingCall(call) {
    try{
        console.log(call.properties.CallSid);
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        console.log("An error occurred while retrieving callsid properties from call object.");
    }

    //show incoming call div
    incomingCallDiv.classList.remove("d-none");

    //add event listeners for Accept, Reject, and Hangup buttons
    incomingCallAcceptButton.onclick = () => {
      acceptIncomingCall(call);
    };

    incomingCallRejectButton.onclick = () => {
      rejectIncomingCall(call);
    };

    incomingCallHangupButton.onclick = () => {
      hangupIncomingCall(call);
    };
}
```

Message that I am getting in the console

```
An error occurred while retrieving callsid properties from call object.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make an outgoing call or recive an incoming call event with the Twilio Voice SDK, the `Call` object has a [`parameters` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall#callparameters) that contains the call parameters you would also receive via the webhook.

So, if you are placing an outgoing call, you can get the call Sid like this:

```js
const device = new Device(token);
const call = await device.connect(options);
console.log(call.parameters.CallSid);
```

Or if you are receiving a call:

```js
const device = new Device(token);
device.on("incoming", call => {
  console.log(call.parameters.CallSid);
})
```

Note that the CallSid you receive here will not match the outbound CallSid to a another phone when placing an outbound call, and will not match the inbound CallSid when receiving the call. Twilio calls between two people (or phone numbers or clients) have a leg for each connection between Twilio and that person, with a different Call Sid for each leg. You can connect the calls together by understanding the call parent. If you are receiving an incoming call, the parent call is the inbound leg. If you are placing an outgoing call, the parent call is that outbound leg. You can [list calls and filter by the parent call Sid using the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#read-multiple-call-resources).

Comment: I am getting below error when reading the properties TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CallSid')

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you are using?

Comment: I have added the code that I am using but it errors out

Comment: What is the error that you get if you don't catch it?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CallSid')An error occurred while retrieving callsid properties from call object. This is when I add err.message

Comment: Ah, that is my fault. The property is called `parameters` and not `properties`. Try logging `call.parameters.CallSid`.